# How to print entire NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, cocoa, pdf, printing, nscollectionview

I'm trying to print entire NSCollectionView. It prints only displayed items, moreover it doesn't render NSCollectionViewItem properly

[image]

Print is populated by bindings using first responder. Method:

```
 @IBAction func printEquations(_ sender: Any) {

    let op = NSPrintOperation(view: collectionView)
    op.canSpawnSeparateThread = true

    let pi = op.printInfo

    pi.horizontalPagination = NSPrintingPaginationMode.fitPagination
    pi.verticalPagination = NSPrintingPaginationMode.fitPagination
    pi.isHorizontallyCentered = true
    pi.isVerticallyCentered = true
    pi.isSelectionOnly = false

    pi.orientation = NSPaperOrientation.portrait
    pi.leftMargin = 10
    pi.rightMargin = 10

    op.run()


}
```

NSCollectionView subclass:

```
class EQCollectionView: NSCollectionView {

var printRect: NSRect?

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

    if (NSGraphicsContext.currentContextDrawingToScreen()) {

        self.layer!.borderWidth = 0
        self.layer!.borderColor = nil
        self.backgroundColors = []
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

    } else {

        self.wantsLayer = true


        let printWidth = Double(calculatePrintWidth())
        let printHeight = Double(calculatePrintHeight())

        printRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: printWidth, height: printHeight)

        super.draw(printRect!)
    }
}



func calculatePrintHeight() -> Float {

    let pi = NSPrintOperation.current()!.printInfo

    let paperSize = pi.paperSize

    let pageHeight = Float(paperSize.height - pi.topMargin - pi.bottomMargin)

    let scale = Float(pi.dictionary().object(forKey: NSPrintScalingFactor) as! CGFloat)

    return pageHeight / scale
}

func calculatePrintWidth() -> Float {

    let pi = NSPrintOperation.current()!.printInfo

    let paperSize = pi.paperSize

    let pageWidth = Float(paperSize.width - pi.leftMargin - pi.rightMargin)

    let scale = Float(pi.dictionary().object(forKey: NSPrintScalingFactor) as! CGFloat)

    return pageWidth / scale
}

override func knowsPageRange(_ range: NSRangePointer) -> Bool {
    range.pointee.location = 1
    range.pointee.length = 1
    return true
}


override func rectForPage(_ page: Int) -> NSRect {

    let bounds = self.bounds
    let pageHeight = calculatePrintHeight()

    let rect = NSMakeRect( NSMinX(bounds), NSMinY(bounds), frame.width, CGFloat(pageHeight));


    return rect;
}
```

}

How to print NSCollectionView with all available content?

Comment: `rectForPage` should return "A rectangle defining the region of the receiver to be printed for pageNumber.". If `horizontalPagination` and `verticalPagination` are `fitPagination` and `knowsPageRange` returns 1, `rectForPage` should return the entire view.

Comment: it doesn't work either. Could you, please, be more specific?

Comment: Are the returned sizes of `calculatePrintHeight` and `calculatePrintWidth` paper sizes or view sizes?

Comment: how do I calculate the correct sizes?

Comment: If you want to print the entire view on one page: return `bounds` from `rectForPage` and call `super.draw(dirtyRect!)` in `draw`.

Comment: How can I get full size of NSCollectionView? i've tried NSView#bounds and NSView#frame methods.

Comment: Apparently, `NSCollectionView` and/or the items don't behave like other views. Print an offscreen view which is big enough to show all items.

Comment: @Willeke you mean to do not use NSCollectionView at all or create a new NSCollectionView offscreen and print it?

Comment: The offscreen view can be a `NSCollectionView` or a different view.